# Problema com ícone de notificação

Tags: java, android, firebase

Sei que há várias perguntas relacionadas a isso. Porém, eu não encontrei nada com o meu caso específico. Vou explicar...

Eu uso o mesmo código para exibir uma notificação tanto para notificações quando o aplicativo está em primeiro plano quanto para em segundo plano. Veja:

```
final int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_name; // aqui está a imagem

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;

        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext, CHANNEL_ID);

        Notification notification;

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);
        notification = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .build();
        Log.i("Notificação -> ", "Foi gerada");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

E em ambos os casos eles mostram a notificação com sucesso, porém apenas quando o aplicativo está em segundo plano a imagem apresenta erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não acredito que o erro esteja na imagem, mas posso estar enganado. Pesquisei sobre o padrão do android para versões anteriores ao lollipop e acredito que estou atuando da forma correta... Mas... Posso estar enganado de novo. O que seria estranho, pois porque o android apresentaria a imagem de uma forma e de outra não?

Alguém sugere alguma coisa? Se precisarem de mais informações estarei a disposição.

**Observações**

*1 - Mesmo eu criando um vector asset em xml com o android studio o resultado é exatamente igual.*

*2 - Fiz testes em vários emuladores diferentes e o resultado é o mesmo.*

Comment: Pode ser que ela não esteja passando por essa função quando em segundo plano e utilizando o padrão do firebase, faça o seguinte teste  substitua o `.setContentText(message)` por `.setContentText("Passou por minha função")`, mande push com uma mensagem diferente e veja o que acontece

Comment: @IcaroMartins vou verificar. 1 minuto.

Comment: @IcaroMartins o problema é exatamente esse.

Comment: @IcaroMartins eu nunca ia imaginar... XD .. A mensagem sempre era exibida!

Comment: @IcaroMartins obrigado cara! Eu queria fazer você ganhar esses duzentinhos... =)

Comment: Agora você tem duas opções: 1) você pode mandar o icon pela configuração do push como foi mostrado na resposta abaixo. o problema é que não vai chegar em sua função. 2) Fazer o push de forma que o firebase sempre passe chame uma função sua, infelizmente nunca fiz isso mas talvez esse link te ajude https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/2456894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após fazer o teste trocando o

> .setContentText(message)

por

> .setContentText("Passou por minha função")

da função que deveria esta sendo chamada

Foi constatado que o `firebase` estava tratando o `push` quando o aplicativo estava em `background` e por isso a imagem não estava aparecendo.

Sabendo disso temos duas opções:

- Pode-se mandar o icon pela configuração do `push`. O problema nesse caso é que se for essencial que o `push` passe pela função, essa solução não ira resolver.
- Fazer o `push` de forma que o `firebase` sempre passe pela função. Infelizmente nunca fiz isso mas talvez esse link te ajude https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/2456894

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda... Não aguentava mais e não achava o erro! Abraço!

Comment: Daqui 21h eu vou te transferir os 200 pra sua conta ok? kkk Está bloqueado! Abraço!

Comment: Tranquilo cara, infelizmente esse outro modo de `push` eu nunca testei então não posso ajudar mais. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Realize o seguinte Teste:

```
{
  "to": "MYDEVICETOKEN",
  "notification": {
    "body": "Test from postman",
    "icon": "ic_notification"
  }
}
```

Comment: Como assim? Colocar o ícone no json? Não entendi amigo... Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: É uma saída, você pode tentar utilizar desta forma também : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: E como eu usaria esse ícone no json na notificação? `.setSmallIcon(icon)` de que forma?

Comment: Eu já olhei a documentação várias vezes... Mas continuo sem entender.

Comment: Provavelmente quando o aplicativo está em segundo plano a forma de exibir esse ícone é diferente. Mas eu não sei como.